# How would I send the ping of my bot over to a json file? Discord.js

Tags: discord.js

I want to transfer the ping of my bot into a json file so the other people developing with me can access the ping through the json file and add with their ping in one embed in a message.

I just sort of need help with the transferring part, how would I do that? I've been searching up a bunch of different things, and I don't know what to do.

I tried this, but someone else said that I have to append it, but I'm not sure how I would do that.

```
const botPing = Math.round(client.ws.ping);

const fs = require('fs');

let jsPing = {jsping: botPing};
 
let data = JSON.stringify(jsPing);
fs.writeFileSync('config.json', data);
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to assume that you are trying to read the json file and send out the ping. To do this you can simply do

```js
let rawdata = fs.readFileSync('config.json');
let parsed = JSON.parse(rawdata);
message.channel.send(`The bot's recorded ping was: ${parsed.jsPing}`);
```